# GCP-PUBSUB:-sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am facing a weird problem.I created a pubsub topic and publishing messages to topic.When I use java main method ,i can successfully publish messages, but when I use a diffrent method calls message is not published.When I debug ,i see call is hanging at
code in both method is 100% same

```
List<String> messageIds = ApiFutures.allAsList(futures).get();
```

How to publish message using non-main method.
Here is my code below.

```
@Slf4j
public class GCPMessagePublisher {

    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "myProjId";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
     
       String topicId = "testTopic";
        int messageCount = 10;
        String message="Hello GCP";
        ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, topicId);

        List<ApiFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        Publisher publisher=null;

        try {
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("GCP Credential Here........"));

            publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();


                // convert message to bytes
                ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
                PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                        .setData(data)
                        .build();

                // Schedule a message to be published. Messages are automatically batched.
                ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
                futures.add(future);

        } finally {
            // Wait on any pending requests
            List<String> messageIds = ApiFutures.allAsList(futures).get();

            for (String messageId : messageIds) {
                System.out.println("messageId Printing is "+messageId);
            }

            if (publisher != null) {
                // When finished with the partypublisher, shutdown to free up resources.
                publisher.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void putMessageOnGCP(String Message) throws Exception
    {

        //log.info("The outgoing message to GCP PUBSUB is : "+message);
 
        String topicId = "testTopic";
        String message="Hi GCP";
        ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, topicId);

        List<ApiFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        Publisher publisher=null;

        try {
            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("GCP Credential Here.........."));

            publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();

                // convert message to bytes
                ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
                PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                        .setData(data)
                        .build();

                // Schedule a message to be published. Messages are automatically batched.
                ApiFuture<String> future = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
                futures.add(future);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally {
            // Wait on any pending requests
            List<String> messageIds = ApiFutures.allAsList(futures).get();

            for (String messageId : messageIds) {
                System.out.println(messageId);
            }

            if (publisher != null) {
                // When finished with the partypublisher, shutdown to free up resources.
                publisher.shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I call from other method I am getting following error.When I check the google credentials I can see it is reading content from Google Credentials JSON File.

```
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:69)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1039)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1165)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:958)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:749)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:522)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:497)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:426)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$500(ClientCallImpl.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:689)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$900(ClientCallImpl.java:577)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:751)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:740)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1728)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:770)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:519)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1043)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:934)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1392)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1224)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1271)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:505)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:444)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:283)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:700)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:635)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:552)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:514)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:290)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:141)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:248)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:699)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:589)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1172)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1289)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:199)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1329)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 34 more
```

Do I have to add anything to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found Answer myself.This happening due to other my personal truststore messing up with GCP.So the solution is

1. Go to google cloud pubsub topic  https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. import the GlobalSignCert
3. Add the cert to your truststore

**Note:If you are using different truststore for your app follow above steps. CACERTS by default support this.**

[image]